# Using regex to remove rows from column in pandas with loc operator

Tags: python, pandas

I have big dataframe which I want to remove all rows where the word `'test'` appears in the column `Source` (`object` type).
However this word can be in many varieties of forms, ex:

```
'test'
'Test'
'TESTE'
```

How can I use case insensitive with regex to remove these rows from my dataframe?
I've tried the following:

```
mask = df.iloc[:,'Source'].str.contains('/test/ig', regex = True)
df = df.loc[~mask]
```

Comment: ``.str.contains('test', case = False)``, would make it case-insensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is used for integer-location based, use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for conditional.
And like @sushanth said, use case = False

```
mask = df.loc[:,'Source'].str.contains('test', case = False)
df = df.loc[~mask]
```